# Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 Not booting, Not charging and not allowing to factory-reset

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7

Issue: My Samsung Galaxy tab is not booting. And when I tried to "factory-reset" by pressing `Volume Key + Power Button` (I hold it for more that 1-minute), still, it does not showed me "factory-reset" screen.

- I kept Device for charging for nearly 3-Hours: No charging indicator is shown.
- It did not show up when connected to PC

I used this tablet for nearly 2-Years, seeing this issue for the first time.

**VERY IMP: Device came in contact of water and since then it is not booting.**

What options I try before taking device to Samsung service center??

Device: Samsung Galaxy Tab 2

Android OS Version: 4.1 Jelly Bean

Comment: Pretty sure you answered your own question, probably has water damage.  Does anything show up when you try to power it on?  Did you let it dry out for a few days before you tried turning it on after the water came into contact with it?

Comment: Nothing. Phone is not showing any display! This happened just 5-6 Hours ago. Shall I wait for few days for it to "DRY"? May be a Week??

Comment: I would, but you might have already done harm trying to turn it on when it was wet.  I would definitely give it a couple days to dry out before I try to do anything more to it.

Comment: It probably isn't bad if you dripped a little water, but if it was submerged in water (*for example, a swimming pool accident*) then the damage can be major. You should probably try to submerge it in an absorbent for a few days (*eg. put it in a bag of rice*).

Comment: Device came into a contract of less amount of water as far as i can see... As soon as i noticed that device is coming into contact of water i quickly moved it away from the water but even by that time the damage was already done and since then it is not booting at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to recover my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 after it came in contact of water.

Writing this in case if anyone in future faces the issue:

1. I Kept the device on charging for almost 6 Hours.
2. Next day, I kept the device in Dry and Sunny Place-Under direct Sunshine, for at about 4-5 Hours. During this "soak" exercise, the temperature was about 27-28 Degree C.
3. I then turned on Device as usual(just by pressing Power key, no factory-reset), and it booted, and it reached Home Screen too. But after 2-3 Hours, it again auto-switched off.
4. Next day, I again repeated step-2
5. Finally, after 2-3 "soak" exercise (meaning keeping device in direct sunshine), now device is working without any issue.

This is by no means a full-proof method, but the one worked for me and may help someone, just in case!!